# Escoger la fotografia en un form con selects

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer un formulario que a través de selects, se pueda escoger una de las tres imagenes disponibles. Estoy empezando en esto y me gustaría que alguien pudiera decirme porqué mi pequeño programa no funciona.

En consola me aparece // Uncaught ReferenceError: var img= form.escogerImg.selectedIndex; form is not defined. Y realmente no entiendo porque porque ya está definida.

```
    <script>
    var galeria="";


    function inicio(){
        galeria=document.querySelectorAll("img");
        ocultar();
        galeria[0].style.display="block";
    }

    function ocultar(){
        galeria.forEach(function(enCadaImagen){
            enCadaImagen.style.display="none";
        });
    }


        var img= form.escogerImg.selectedIndex;

        if (form.escogerImg.options[img].value=="img1"){
            ocultar();
            galeria[0].style.display="block";
        }
        else if (form.escogerImg.options[img].value=="img2"){
            ocultar();
            galeria[1].style.display="block";
        }
        else if (form.escogerImg.options[img].value=="img3"){
            ocultar();
            galeria[2].style.display="block";
        }


    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="inicio()">
        <center>
            <div>
                <h1>Galeria de imágenes</h1>
            </div>
           <form>
            <div id="galeriaImg">
                <img src="img/messi.jpeg" alt="">
                <img src="img/umtiti.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/iniesta.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

                <select size="1" name="escogerImg">
                    <option value="img1">Messi</option>
                    <option value="img2">Umtiti</option>
                    <option value="img3">Iniesta</option>
                </select>

            </form>
        </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Intenta poner el script despues del body

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: El problema puede ser que tal y como se carga la pagina, el script está antes de que se cargue el formulario, es una buena práctica poner siempre los script y los link hacia los ficheros .js al final del body, justo antes de la etiqueta </body>. Prueba a hacerlo así.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiar esta linea:

```
var img= form.escogerImg.selectedIndex;
```

Por esta:

```
var img= document.forms[0].escogerImg.selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Sigue apareciendo exactamente el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea:

```
var img= form.escogerImg.selectedIndex;
```

Estás intentando crear la variable img con el valor de un atributo de la variable form... que no has declarado en ningún sitio.
Puedes añadir justo antes algo como

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
```

Pero de todos modos el código no hará lo que quieres porque la comprobación la tienes que hacer cuando el usuario elija algo, luego necesitas capturar el evento "seleccionar una opción en tu select:

```js
var galeria="";


function inicio(){
    galeria=document.querySelectorAll("img");
    ocultar();
    galeria[0].style.display="block";

    // La parte que te faltaba: escuchar los cambios
    let select= document.querySelector('select');
    select.addEventListener('change',function (event) {
      let index=select.selectedIndex;
       if (select.options[index].value=="img1"){
            ocultar();
            galeria[0].style.display="block";
        }
        else if (select.options[index].value=="img2"){
            ocultar();
            galeria[1].style.display="block";
        }
        else if (select.options[index].value==="img3"){
            ocultar();
            galeria[2].style.display="block";
        }
    });
}

function ocultar(){
    galeria.forEach(function(enCadaImagen){
        enCadaImagen.style.display="none";
    });
}

inicio();
```

```html
<center>
  <div>
      <h1>Galeria de imágenes</h1>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div id="galeriaImg">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>

    <select size="1" name="escogerImg">
      <option value="img1">Messi</option>
      <option value="img2">Umtiti</option>
      <option value="img3">Iniesta</option>
    </select>

  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer, es crear una variable que guarde el valor del elemento seleccionado en el select. Si te fijas, luego ese valor entra en condicionales para ejecutar una orden. Con lo que me dices, no estaría guardando el elemento seleccionado en el select y no lo podría evaluar en los condicionales.

Comment: Y por cierto, creo que sí lo he declarado. He declarado un form en el body, con nombre escogerImg.

Comment: No habías declarado la variable form, sí tienes un form en el HTML, pero la forma de acceder a él no es automática

Answer (score 0):

0
votar en contra
El problema puede ser que tal y como se carga la pagina, el script está antes de que se cargue el formulario, es una buena práctica poner siempre los script y los link hacia los ficheros .js al final del body, justo antes de la etiqueta . Prueba a hacerlo así.